# How to apply multiple combine condition in T-SQL and not let these condition individually effect result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two tables Question and Answers. Question table have column 'QuestionType' and its value is either 1 if question is of type text and 2 if question has pre-define answer options for example radio, drop-down

I am trying T-SQL where I need only answers against question if answer has value. now for QuestionType if value is null or empty then that is mean no answer which will be fillter out but for QuestionType 2, it will always null even if there is answer because there is another table holding that information.

I need Answer where value exist but also also questionType of 2 even with Null value in Answer

i did in following but condition rule out of questionType 2 which I don't want

```
FROM [dbo].[MyTable] AS sur
INNER JOIN [dbo].[SurveyQuestions] AS surQus ON sur.Id = surQus.SurveyId
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Questions] AS qus ON surQus.QuestionId = qus.Id
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Responses] AS res ON res.SurveyId = sur.Id
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Answers] AS ans ON res.Id = ans.ResponseId AND qus.Id = ans.QuestionId 
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[AnswerOptions] AS ansOpt ON ans.Id = ansOpt.AnswerId
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[QuestionOptions] AS qusOpt ON ansOpt.QuestionOptionId = qusOpt.Id
 WHERE con.Id = '00000011-0013-4D34-8888-7E7189CA348U'
    AND (qus.QuestionType ='1' AND ans.Value IS NOT NULL ) //???????? NEED HELP HERE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question you need an OR statement, with each set of conditions in their own set of parenthesis, surrounded by one main set of parenthesis.

```
FROM [dbo].[MyTable] AS sur
INNER JOIN [dbo].[SurveyQuestions] AS surQus ON sur.Id = surQus.SurveyId
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Questions] AS qus ON surQus.QuestionId = qus.Id
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Responses] AS res ON res.SurveyId = sur.Id
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Answers] AS ans ON res.Id = ans.ResponseId AND qus.Id = ans.QuestionId 
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[AnswerOptions] AS ansOpt ON ans.Id = ansOpt.AnswerId
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[QuestionOptions] AS qusOpt ON ansOpt.QuestionOptionId = qusOpt.Id
 WHERE con.Id = '00000011-0013-4D34-8888-7E7189CA348U'
    AND (
        (qus.QuestionType ='1' AND ans.Value IS NOT NULL )
        OR
        (qus.QuestionType ='2')
        )
```